# Mangasarian lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

The task is to show that either there is such $x>0$ that $Ax \leq 0$ or there is $y\geq 0$ such that $A^Ty\geq 0$ and  $A^Ty \not= 0$ where $A$ is $m\times n$ matrix.

I know how to show that we can't have both but I have some troubles with further actions. So we need to show that if the first condition does not hold then the second one does. So if there are no $x>0$ for which $Ax\leq 0$ then there should be some $y \geq 0$ such that $A^Ty\geq 0$. Maybe it is possible to apply Farkas lemma here somehow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this the correct statement? It seems that $y = 0$ **always** satisfies the second system.

Comment: oops, forget to add $A^Ty \not= 0$